# POSTGRESQL COPY AND ERROR LOGGING syntax error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to read in a txt file that has an empty line at the end, so I added (ERROR_LOGGING, ERROR_LOGGING_MAX_ERRORS 2). There was an syntax error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: COPY  table_name FROM STDIN DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER (ERROR_LOGG...

Here is my full query:
**\copy table_name FROM '/Documents/sample_file.tsv' 
DELIMITER E'\t' 
CSV 
HEADER 
(ERROR_LOGGING, ERROR_LOGGING_MAX_ERRORS 2);**

Please help!

Comment: I assume you're getting this from [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Error_logging_in_COPY)? As it says in the first paragraph, "Error logging in COPY was a **proposed** feature". It was never released. All of the available options are listed in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: Nick, Thanks for the info. Is there a way we can allow a certain number of errors with COPY command?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. You might have to `COPY` to a temp table and validate the data yourself.

Comment: That's a huge txt file and never had a chance to completely open the file and validate the data. :((